# why java.lang.NullPointerException is occured?

Tags: java, constructor, nullpointerexception

Firstly i am not expert in Java.So my question(s) may be silly.Please forgive if i mistaken.This is from OCJP MCQ.I have written following code

```
public class Test{
Integer a;
int b;

public Test(Integer x) {
    b = a+x;
    System.out.println(""+b);
}

public static void main(String... str)
{
    new Test(new Integer("10"));
}}
```

> **Output:** Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

I have following question in my mind,

**1. Does `Integer a` and `int b` are initialized to 0 before statement `b=a+x;` is executed**

**2. Why it is throwing NullPointerException.**

Your response will be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: `a` is initialised to null.  `b` is initialised to 0.  So you're trying to add something to null - you can't do that.

Comment: @DavidWallace Most of the time you put answers in comments. Better to post that as an answer.

Comment: No, it amuses me to see how many upvotes people get when they copy my comments into answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All object references are initialised to `null` in Java. So that means that the property `Integer a` will be null because it has not been initialised. Therefore, that means that when `b = a+x;` is executed, you are actually adding the variable `x` to the reference variable `a` that is `null`.

To initialise the property `Integer a`:

```
Integer a = new Integer(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You hit by the below [`reason specified in Docs`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html),

```
Calling the instance method of a null object.
```

By default reference will be initialized to `null`, Where as orimirives set to default primitive values.

```
Data Type   Default Value (for fields)
byte    0
short   0
int 0
long    0L
float   0.0f
double  0.0d
char    '\u0000'
**String (or any object)    null** //Integer is Object, int is not
boolean false
```

When you try to do Unboxing , i.e

```
 wrapperIntegerObject.intValue();   //wrapperIntegerObject is null
```

Comment: which method it executed internally cause exception

Comment: It's not the method; it's the auto-unboxing.

Comment: Yes, I would say when you try to invoke `intValue()`

Answer (score 1):

null+any number you will get NullPointerException.

to illustrate try the below code.

```
  static Integer a;
  public static void main(String[] ar) {
       System.out.println(a);
       System.out.println(a+10);
  }
```